# When did countries start developing military aircraft?

Tags: war, cold-war

When, where and which countries developed the most powerful military aircraft?

.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a history related question, and even for other sites of SE is too broad and without any prior research.

Comment: Yes, ok. I'm sorry. It is the first time that I am using this app, I had no idea how to do that. By the way, I think this question have a intrinsic relation about historical, I mean, France has its industry in Mali cause the cologne, Russia with countries that have alliance after the wars. I think all the issues can be seeing by this point. One more time again, sorry.

Comment: Countries have developed arms and munitions from before historical records.

Comment: Military Aircraft.  Omg! Sorry!

Comment: If you believe you can improve it, I'd suggest clicking the "edit" text (button) under your question and doing so. I will add that in its current form, the question text and its title appear to be asking two completely different questions.

Comment: @RabiscosDaLu By "military aircraft" do you mean "aircraft used by the military" in general or weaponized aircraft in particular? If the former, then military aircraft have been in use since possibly as early as 500 BC when the Chinese used kites for military communications.

Comment: @called2voyage , wow! I'll make some research about. I want to discover who wins with wars. I mean, what I'm seeing in the world is crazy, doesn't make sense. By this I want to understand all this! And yes, I'm lost with all this thousands of informations.

Comment: If you want to know about aviation history, you would probably do better asking it on Aviation.SE.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann , thank you! I found some information about Lockheed Martin. I need spending more time on that site. There are a lot of companies working for its. This issue is really crazy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there isn't really an answer on your question.

There aren't fixed country's producing weapons. In history there were a lot different weapon factory's from state-owned weapon factory's to private weapon company's.

Who is responsible for that? The one who said he can develop weapons and take an offer from someone who want weapons. [A link for this from Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_modern_armament_manufacturers)

To get better answers you have to specify the time range, maybe the war and which country you mean.

New answer (OP changed question).

The first munition was developed from  1250A.D. in china and later from 1324 in Europe, after the invention of black powder. In china they first used bamboo sticks which shot something out. Later in Europe they first built cannons mostly local at the beginning, cause the transport wasn't really easy.

Comment: Hi, Anetair. You are right, I think I need putting some limits in this question. I think I need start to looking for information about Russia and USA weapons. Thank you for replying me. :)

Comment: Also this isn't that specific, cause this are two really big country's and have each a large army. In addition, the time would also be nice, cause there were a lot changes since like ww2 and today.

Comment: Yes. Omg! I think to find all the answers that I want/need is crazy! I heard that France has a industry in Mali, now I want to find ways to check that and others industries. I'll start to find something about Russia army. Omg ><  Tks again!

Comment: No Problem I would recommend you to search the russian/usa army in Wikipedia. Mostly you get some info's about weapons types or tank models there. And with this it isn't really a big problem to get out who is producing them.

Comment: Wow! Yes! Start knowing the names of tank models and guns will help me a lot! Did you follow the Turkey Cop? I was scared when I saw that airplanes. They are huge! Where are they from? I can't stop this question on my mind!

Comment: Don't exactly know which you mean of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_Air_Force

Comment: Thank you ! They will close my question cause I wrote that in the wrong way >< it is the first time that I am here and I made mistake lol. Where can I put one question like this?

Comment: Good question, if you say when (even the last fey years) and what (which type or from which company the imported the most) and which country, i think you can place it here.

Comment: I changed :D. Is it better now?

Comment: yes, way better

Comment: Tks!!! I think I am understanding this app now... lol

Comment: We were speaking about munition from fire weapons (not bows or similar), but op wasn't exactly sure how to ask the question, so it was difficult to answer.

Comment: @user20995 but i would recommend to open a new question. This here is a bit complicated now ;)

Comment: I'll do that #shame

Answer (score 0):

The first weapon was a rock or stick used by one proto-human to bash another over the head...
And we've been getting every better at it ever since.
No country needed, though with the cost of large scale weapons development in the 20th century (or really from the Roman era) it certainly helps to have the resources of a country at your disposal.

Comment: An aircraft would be any device heavier than air capable of flight (not flying like a rock) by providing it's own lift (via a wing) The first flight was without any doubt the Wright Flyer as they produced the first truly aerodynamic wing capable of creating said "lifting body." This was no military aircraft however. If we're talking performance then nothing beats Herman Goring's Luftwaffe for military aircraft. As far as firepower, reliability, lethality and "military economy" nothing can touch the US Army Airforce of World War 2.

Comment: @user14394 The question originally asked about munitions, not aircraft, by mistake.

Comment: A "munition" can be recovered under the same rubric. A "rock" is not a munition nor is an axe or a bow as the term implies a specified item held in stowage for said specified purpose. For example a box of rocks or a quiver of arrows are "munitions" as the implication is one of design for said purpose as use as a weapon to inflict harm on another...including non humans.

Comment: @user14394 tell that to the person using a slingshot or a balista. They use rocks/stones as munitions. It doesn't have to be kept in a box for the purpose, much as a ball round for a musket was often carried loose in someone's pocket.